# Magento-Custom shopping cart price rule - Buy 2 different products and get those for flate rate?

Tags: magento, cart, magento-rules

I want to set up different kind of price rules(shopping cart price rules) for my client. I tried default magento's extension, but I couldn't. when I searched in the net, some solutions told that using observer can solve my problem. But those weren't enough for me. Let me explain one of my problem.

Buy 2 different products and get those for flat rate.

Say, Product X is 700 and Product Y is 500. When customer buys those 2 products (Total 1200), he can get both products for 1000.

is there any straight way to do this or should need to create custom module with database table and observer?

Comment: you want it for the specific 2 products or on cart total (Total 1200)?

Comment: I'll explain more clearly. When admin create a rule, he should be able to add 2 products which are eligible for discount. So when customer add those specific 2 products(not when cart total is 1200), in the cart discount amount 200 (instead of 1200, will be charged 1000 only) should be displayed with specific label.

Comment: If product X is $700 and product y is $500, why not create a discount of $200 to make it equal to $1000?  You can also create a Bundled Product that combines both products into a bundle, with a fixed price of $1,000.

Comment: Thanks @Axel , if I understand Vijay's point correctly what I intend to do is, say I got a few products in a category.
I cannot create a bundle product as I intend to sell X items of these at fixed price. Prices of these individual products are differnet so fixed price rule is not possible. Plus, i need the experience to be as other purchases so am avoiding bundle products.
Hope I am clear with my question

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

1. First Specified Your `X` and `Y` `SKU` and put this condition and action and apply discount amount.
2. If you don't found `SKU` in condition, then change in the `SKU` attribute to apply shopping rule to `YES`